# How to convert $\theta = \pi/3$ into cartesian form?

Tags: polar-coordinates

How can I convert

$$\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$$

into cartesian form?

What I get is

$$
\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}\\
cos(\theta) = \frac{x}{r} = \frac{1}{2}\\
x = \frac{r}{2}
$$

and I'm not sure what the next step should be.

Comment: What do you mean by Cartesian form, do you mean all $(x,y) $ such that $(x,y) = r (\cos {\pi \over 3}, \sin {\pi \over 3})$? Maybe with $r \ge 0$?

Comment: @copper.hat I mean cartesian equation.

Comment: You need a radius to convert it to Cartesian form, and I don't know if your instructor allows negative radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same for y and get $sin{\theta}$=$y\over r$=$\sqrt{3}\over 2$ so y=${\sqrt{3}r}\over 2$

Now plug in r=2x and get y=${\sqrt{3}x}$

Comment: @bowngreen I see, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With the given polar coordinates $(\theta, r)$ the transformation to cartesian coordinates are $$x = r\cos \theta $$ $$ y = r\sin \theta$$ and so the answer to your question would be $x=\frac {r}{2} $ and $y=r\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $.

Answer (score 0):

Hint $x=r\cos(\theta),y=r\sin(\theta)$ where r is the radius of the circle.

Comment: so basically I should arrive at $x = r/2$ and $y = r\sqrt{3}/2$, is that correct?

Comment: Yes right... ...